# Sets of trigonometric equations: solve for $x$

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following  sets of trigonometric equations:

$$\sin(\alpha_n+x)+\sin(\beta_n-x)=c_1$$

For $n=1$ to $n=m$

$$\sin(\alpha_k+x)+\sin(\beta_k-x)=c_2$$

For $k=m+1$ to $k=l$

$$\sin(\alpha_p+x)+\sin(\beta_p-x)=c_3$$

For $p=l+1$ to $p=q$

The $\alpha_n, \beta_n, \alpha_k, \beta_k, \alpha_p, \beta_p, c_1, c_2 \text{ and } c_3$ are **knowns, Real and positive**. Also, $c_1>c_2>c_3$.

I need to find $x$.

Of course if the $\gamma_i$ were $0$ then this would be a doddle but they are not.

Comment: what is $\gamma_i?$

Comment: You have one unknown x but a lot of equations.  Usually one has one equation for one variable. Why do you thinks that such $x$ exists?

Comment: you can use $$\sin{\left( x+{{\alpha }_n}\right) }-\sin{\left( x-{{\beta }_n}\right) } = \left( \cos{\left( {{\alpha }_n}\right) }-\cos{\left( {{\beta }_n}\right) }\right)  \sin{(x)}+\left( \sin{\left( {{\beta }_n}\right) }+\sin{\left( {{\alpha }_n}\right) }\right)  \cos{(x)}$$

Comment: @miracle173 $x$ must exist because the angles are the result of a Bragg diffraction experiment.

Comment: @miracle173 Thanks! I think that solves for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ =, for two simultaneous equations.

Comment: I have the explicit solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Too long for a comment.*

If this is coming from some experiments, I suppose that you have in fact equations like
$$\sin(\alpha_n+x)+\sin(\beta_n-x)=c_{1n}$$ where the $c_{1n}$ are *almost* a constant.

If you assume that  the $c_{1n}$ are *exactly* a constant. then the problem is simple. Take two of the equations and solve for $x$. But, how can you be sure that the obtained solution will satisfy all other equations ?

This problem looks to me very similar to a data reconciliation problem and more  than likely it would need to be solved using optimization.

The rhs being constant or not, you can write all the equations as

$$\sin(\alpha_n+x)+\sin(\beta_n-x)=c_{n}\qquad \text{for} \qquad n=1,2,\cdots, q\tag 1$$ Expanding the sines, defines
$$a_n=\cos(\alpha_n)-\cos(\beta_n)\qquad \text{and} \qquad b_n=\sin(\alpha_n)+\sin(\beta_n)$$ which makes $(1)$ to be
$$a_n \sin(x)+b_n \cos(x)=c_n \tag 2$$
In a preliminary step, let $S=\sin(x)$ and $C=\cos(x)$ and treat the problem as a bilinear regression (ignoring the relation between $S$ and $C$). This is easy to solve using matrix calculations or the normal equations
$$S \sum_{n=1}^q a_n^2+C \sum_{n=1}^q a_nb_n= \sum_{n=1}^q a_nc_n$$
$$S \sum_{n=1}^q a_nb_n+C \sum_{n=1}^q b_n^2= \sum_{n=1}^q b_nc_n$$

Two linear equations the solution of which giving $S$ and $C$ independently of eachother. The problem is that, more than likely
$$S^2+C^2 \neq 1$$ but the obtained values will be very reasonable  starting guesses of the final step.

Now, consider the norm
$$\Phi(S)= \sum_{n=1}^q \Big[a_n S+b_n \sqrt{1-S^2}-c_n\Big]^2$$ which is what you need to minimize to obtain the most probable value of $S=\sin(x)$.

Compute the deivative and set it equal to $0$. This will give  the equation in $S$
$$S \sum_{n=1}^q (a_n^2-b_n^2)+\sqrt{1-S^2}\sum_{n=1}^q a_nb_n+\frac{S}{\sqrt{1-S^2}}\sum_{n=1}^q b_nc_n-\frac{S^2}{\sqrt{1-S^2}}\sum_{n=1}^q a_nb_n-\sum_{n=1}^q a_nc_n=0$$ which will be easy to solve using Newton method.

For an illustration example, I shall use three equations.
$$\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{3}-x\right)=1.40\tag 3$$
$$\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{5}-x\right)=0.85\tag 4$$
$$\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{12}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{6}-x\right)=0.67\tag 5$$

Solving $(3)$ gives $x=0.620904$; solving $(4)$ gives $x=0.63382$; solving $(5)$ gives $x=0.635439$; they are close but different.

Using the proposed procedure will give $x_{\text{opt}}=0.626170$. Recomputing the three rhs will give $1.39605$, $0.853664$ , $0.673401$.

**Edit**

If the $c_n$, $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ are perfectly known, there is not much choice.

Using the tangent half-angle substitution $x=2\tan^{-1}(t)$, each equation is a quadratic in $t$
$$(b_n+c_n)t^2-2a_nt +(c_n-b_n)=0\implies t_n^{\pm}=\frac{a_n\pm\sqrt{a_n^2+b_n^2-c_n^2}}{b_n+c_n}$$ Solve all of them and perform some statistical analysis.

**Update**

There is something which could be interesting to try which takes into account the structure of your data.

The idea will be to obtain the best $x_1$ for $c_1$, $x_2$ for $c_2$ and $x_3$ for $c_3$.

Say for $c_1$, consider the $\frac 12n(n-1)$ equations
$$f_{ij}=(a_i-a_j) \sin(x)+(b_i-b_j) \cos(x)$$ which, in the ideal case should be equal to $0$ and now consider the norm
$$\Phi(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \Big[(a_i-a_j) \sin(x)+(b_i-b_j) \cos(x)\Big]^2$$ and this becomes a simple optimization problem in one dimension.

For illustration purposes, for $c=1$ and the following parameters
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha_n & \beta_n \\
 0.12 & 0.92 \\
 0.23 & 0.82 \\
 0.34 & 0.74 \\
 0.46 & 0.66 \\
 0.57 & 0.59 \\
 0.68 & 0.54
\end{array}
\right)$$

This leads to $x=0.453886$ and for this value $\Phi_{\text{min}}=2.324\times 10^{-4}$.

Working a bit more, we can get the explicit solution. Let $A_{k}=(a_i-a_j)$ and $B_{k}=(b_i-b_j)$

$$\tan(2x)=2\frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{\frac 12n(n-1)}A_k\,B_k} {\sum_{k=1}^{\frac 12n(n-1)}\left(B^2_k-A^2_k\right) } \quad \implies x=$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The $c$ are in fact *known precisely* because thety're not the result of some measurement. +1 with an option to accept later.

Comment: Thanks for the expansion tio your answer!